# I am not able to use tailwind css with React

Tags: reactjs, npm, tailwind-css, npx

I'm trying to use tailwindCSS along with react I used the following commands ...........................................................

```bash
npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer
```

```bash
npx tailwindcss init -p
```

After running autoprefixer command line then I tried using  npx command but it showed me an error and was not able to load tailwind file...................................
After typing command all the required command lines I got this error message I already have react installed.
Please Help me to solve this problem........................................................
The autoprefixer command line has worked perfectly but when I used npx command line I got an error.....................................................................................

```bash
'React' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
  operable program or batch file.   
  throw err;
^
  Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\HP\Downloads\tailwindcss\lib\cli.js'
at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:15)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:990:27)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:142:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
    requireStack: []
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.